# Execute command with various variables in one line with xargs

Tags: linux, console, xargs, usergroups

To be quick, this is my command:

```
echo "user1,user2,user3" | xargs -d, -L 1 usermod -g specialgroup
```

I want to add multiple existing users to a single group in one single command line. But, the above doesn't work, however if you put:

```
echo "user1,user2,user3" | xargs -d, -L 1 echo
```

It lists you the three users:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

Any idea on how I could do it? Even if it's without the xargs.

Comment: I'm assuming that you've tested that it works when you pass the three usernames manually?

Comment: I don't quite understand your top line. What's with the asterisks and having echo at the end?

Comment: Are not asteriscs... it was supposed to to make toe font BOLD, but someone edited my question and left the format things... And yes, I have tested it manually and it works 100%.

Comment: Got it. I think Anton's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a final newline written by `echo`, `user3` becomes `user3\n`. I've tested your example (removing formatting attempts and extraneous `echo`s from the code), and I've found it's the only problem preventing it from working.

Use `echo -n "user1,user2,user3"` to avoid final newline.

Comment: There's also `adduser` (which is normally used for user creation, but it does add user to group with `adduser user group` syntax). And you should say *how* it doesn't work (error message? or everything looks good but no effect? (and how do you check it)). Note that these commands are normally in `/usr/sbin`, and you have to be `root` to use them.

Comment: IT WORKED! My mistake, I wasn't removing the "echo" from the end.